# "Object Library invalid or contains references..." in Excel VBA with DatePicker

Tags: vba, excel, activex, registry

I have been working on a Excel workbook with lots of VBA code for a while and now I have send this file to some colleagues for testing and it does NOT work in their computer.
We all work in the same company and have Windows XP SP2 with Office 2003.

The workbook has a form that opens when clicking over a shape and it contains some controls.
When they click over the shape for the form to show the following error appears:

> "Object Library invalid or contains
>   references to object defintions that
>   could not be found"

In the form there is a DatePicker and I think there lies the problem.  If I delete the datePicker from the form and send them the file again they do not get this error message.

I already tried deleting the mscomct2.exd file as mentioned in this two sites "[Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290537)" and "[lessanvaezi](http://www.lessanvaezi.com/delete-exd-files-to-fix-object-library-invalid-error/)" but the error stil pops.  I checked and the new .exd file was generated.

Some Additional info:

1. I check their system and they do have the file mscomct2.ocx in the correct location(c:\Winxp\System32).
2. If I open a empty Excel file, go to the VBA editor go to Tools->Reference, I do NOT see the option to register the "Microsoft Common Control-2 6.0 (SP6)" (mscomct2.ocx). Instead I see a "Microsoft Windows Common Controls Satellite-3 6.2)" (cmct3de.dll).
3. I send my collegue the file with the datePicker, but without the reference to the "Microsoft Common Control-2 6.0 (SP6)".  Before clicking the shape and opening the form I tried to reference the MSCOMCT2.ocx library dinamically with the following code.  It referenced the "Microsoft Common Control-2 6.0 (SP6)" but the error still pops.

> Sub RegisterCtl()
>
> ```
> 'MSComCt2.ocx
> strGUID = "{86CF1D34-0C5F-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}"
> ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid guid:=strGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0
> ```
>
> end Sub

1. If I then go to the form in the VBE editor and rightClick on the
   toolbox and then go to the
   Additional controls to add the
   "Microsoft Date and TimePicker"
   control, I see that option listed
   Two times.  Unfortunatelly regarless
   of wich one I cchose, the behaviour
   is the same: The datepicker symbol
   is added in the toolbox, but when I
   drag the control to the form, a
   msgBox pops saying that the control
   was not available.

Has anybody an idea what is wrong? What can I do to make it run in their computer?

I appreciate any help.

**Edit:**

The computer with this problem has been Upgraded so I wont be able to find the specific solution for my case.  I'm choosing Archers solution as it has helped the most people (Most Upvotes).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same problem too. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957924/en-us delete all .exd files make my program work!

Go into a command prompt and type the following DOS commands:

Code:

> CD \Documents and Settings
>
> DEL /S /A:H /A:-H *.EXD

Comment: I ran the dos command (it deleted "MSComCtl2.exd") but error msg stil pops.

Comment: I am using this solution for the [KB2598041](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2598041) (April 10, 2012) and it works perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings>DEL /S /A:H /A:-H *.EXD
Deleted file - C:\Documents and Settings\*****\Application Data\Microsoft\Forms
\MSComctlLib.exd  
Deleted file - C:\Documents and Settings\****\Local Settings\Temp\Excel8.0\MSF
orms.exd
Deleted file - C:\Documents and Settings\*****\Local Settings\Temp\VBE\MSComctl
Lib.exd
Deleted file - C:\Documents and Settings\*****\Local Settings\Temp\VBE\MSComDlg
.exd
Deleted file - C:\Documents and Settings\*****\Local Settings\Temp\VBE\MSForms.
exd after this the error is gone

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. I cant remember what the reason was, but in your userform where you have the date/time picker, put this in userform_initialize. The code just adds a textbox if they do not have the correct reference. I know its not the BEST solution, but its a workaround. I wasn't able to run regsvr32 on any machines because of our system administrators.

```
Dim dtP As Object
Dim hasDtPicker As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
Set dtP = frmSearch.Frame24.Controls.Add("MSComCtl2.DTPicker", "DTPicker1", True)
If Err.Number <> 0 Or dtP Is Nothing Then
     hasDtPicker = False
     'change "frmsearch.Frame24" to the area where you want the date and time picker to be.
     Set dtP = frmSearch.Frame24.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "DTPicker1", True)
     dtP.Text = [todays_date].Value
Else
     hasDtPicker = True
End If
'
' formatting properties for both TextBox and DTPicker
'
With dtP
     .Width = 67.5
     .height = 18
     .Left = lblNextActionDate.Left
     .Top = lblNextActionDate.Top + lblNextActionDate.height + 5
End With
```

Comment: Hi @Patrick.  Thanks for the info.  Due to the complexity of my workbook I opted to go DatePicker free.  But I still want to understand what is happening and how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

I think #2 is the root of the problem.  If you can get mscomct2.ocx to show up in Tool - References on a new workbook, it will probably fix the rest of your problems.  Did you try registering the ocx?  Start -  Run - cmd to open a DOS window.  Navigate to the system32 folder.  Type

```
regsvr32 mscomct2.ocx
```

I think that will put the ocx in the Tools - References box and hopefully that fixes it.  Here's a link for insalling the ocx on Windows 7

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/05/28/calendar-control-dll-on-windows-7-64-bit/

Not your situation, but maybe helpful.  Also, see MS's page on regsvr32

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249873

Comment: Thanks Dick for your post.  I tried registering, but the error stil pops.  After registering the mscomct2.ocx I check his Tool->Reference and the "Microsoft Common Control-2 6.0 (SP6)" was still not available.

Comment: I Also deleted again the .exd. Interestingly, new .exd file was created with modification date today, but with a creation date of many months ago. Any further suggestion is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem recently. After about two days downloaded new mscomct2.ocx file:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297381
unregistered previous one, manually removed a strange MRU key with "mscomct2" in one of fields (just in case only), registered new one (using Access ActiveX menu).
And all controls from mscomct2.ocx are listed only once since then !

But unfortunately that did not remove error messages. However after double consecutive import to the new container:
original_file.mdb --> db1.mdb --> db2.mdb
error messages do not appear any more (in the db2.mdb file). But they were still visible during trnasfer between original_file.mdb and db1.mdb.

Answer (score 1):

I am having this same problem with a file I sent to another group. I have a date picker in a user form, and the file works fine with the Excel (2007 and 2010) except for the machines in this one group. The error message is the same as in the original posting.

The answer seems to be the following, as described by a support person who looked into it:

It turns out the MSCOMCT2.OCX file was missing from the user's computer.  This file is Microsoft Windows Common Controls-2 6.0 (MSCOMCT2.OCX).  It appears that this control provides the capability in the model to work with the Date Picker.

The process to fix his computer was as follows:

1. Copy mscomct2.ocx file to c:\windows\system32
2. Register the ocx file by running the following command on his computer.  From a command prompt type regsvr32.exe c:\windows\system32\mscomct2.ocx then press Enter.

---

This instruction may be specific to the group's computers, but the identification of mscomct2.ocx as the culprit is a start. I have no specific recommendation of where to get this file, except that it seems to be available on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete startup addins from here (mind Office version):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE12\XLSTART\
```

Comment: Office isn't the only program that uses VBA

Comment: The question is about Excel, no?

Answer (score 1):

Just un-register `MSCOMCTL.OCX` and then register it.

```
**32-bit OS** C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX

**64-Bit OS** C:\Windows\SySWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that the (Name) field on your DatePicker ActiveX control isn't incrementing. I have an excel sheet with a ComboBox in which the name changes everytime I open, and where it is referenced in code it throws this same error.

I reference ComboBox1, but strangely it is now ComboBox17.