# "Object library invalid or contains references to object definitions that could not be found" or "Element not found"

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting this error when I open a workbook(Excel 2007) which having a ActiveX controls. I tried deleting MSForms.exd files, but still getting the same error message. Also I tried to add  MSCOMCTL.OCX file in references but no use.

I would like to know if there any solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you tried deleting *all* "*.exd" files, as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495002/) and its answers?

Comment: I have tried deleting all .exd files, but still that issue am facing.

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded c:\windows\syswow64\fm20.dll from developers machine (newer) to the client (older) and it works fine now (both are 64 bit OSes). Unfortunately administrative privileges are required.

Answer (score 0):

If copy only fm20.dll but It didn't work, but if you upload Languange Library fm20ENU.dll (or the properly language), works.